# How to use vuei18n-po?

Tags: django, vue.js, internationalization, po

i can't find a tutorial how to use package [vuei18n-po](https://github.com/avast/vuei18n-po) in vue main.ts.

Yts documentation is small, and not well descriped.

[image]

https://www.npmjs.com/package/vuei18n-po.

I have never use something like this inside app initiation in vue, so it is realy hard.

**it is my code:**

```
import { createApp } from "vue";
import App from "./App.vue";
import router from "./router";
import "jquery";
import "bootstrap";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
import vuei18nPo from "vuei18n-po";

const app = createApp(App);
await vuei18nPo({
  po: ["django.po", "../../backend/locale/pl/LC_MESSAGES/django.po"],
  messagesFile: "generated/allInOne.json",
  messagesDir: "generated",
});

app.use(router);

app.mount("#app");
```

In my code i did not use plug it in option, because i wanted to generate it first.

**EDIT**
I found this error on localhost

> Module "fs" has been externalized for browser compatibility. Cannot
> access "fs.realpath" in client code.

I dont understand what this mean too.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that this package is meant to be used for client side code regarding the error especially because po is a GUI-based solution.

The [vuei18n-po](https://github.com/avast/vuei18n-po) is meant to transform some files locally with some JS backend like a Node.js app (this is the `Usage` part in package's README).

Then for the 2nd part (`Plug it in`), you could use the generated files with an i18n setup for VueJS with the regular Vue2 package for i18n: https://kazupon.github.io/vue-i18n/
Or the one for Vue3: https://vue-i18n.intlify.dev/

If it's not clear enough, feel free to read articles on how to setup i18n with Vue.

---

This is then a 2 step problem. I recommend that you start with a simple example of 2 small JSON files in Vue, then that you try to convert your `.po` files with the `vuei18n-po` package.

Comment: This is a point. I want to generate a json file, and then use in vue i18n package. But i can't understand how to do it. In my opinion it works, something like that, when i start a server it will automaticaly check and generate a file ( if some changes appear). So if you know how to do it outside of main.ts, something like script sh, i would be greatful.

Comment: @Keso run it in a Node env `node my-script.sh`. Can de done at any `package.json` moment just before another script.

Comment: but how, what should i write to sh script, or maybe you know another solution to convert django po to json. Additionaly, you write about plug it in part, where this part ( like you said) is not important now, i want to generate it first, then next things.

Comment: The `plug it in` part [is here](https://github.com/avast/vuei18n-po#plug-it-in). Oh sorry, you don't need any `sh`, rather `js` so `node my-script.js` of course since it's a node JS script and not a shell-based one. Start by the NodeJS part, then you'll move into the next section of installing it for `vue-i18n` @Keso